# Best way to vectorize operation having input and output history dependence?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

My goal is to vectorize the following operation in numpy,

`y[n] = c1*x[n] + c2*x[n-1] + c3*y[n-1]`

If `n` is time, I essentially need the outputs depending on previous inputs as well as previous outputs. I'm given the values of `x[-1]` and `y[-1]`. Also, this is a generalized version of my actual problem where `c1 = 1.001`, `c2 = -1` and `c3 = 1`.

I could figure out the procedure to add the first two operands, simply by adding `c1*x` and `c2*np.concatenate([x[-1], x[0:-1])`, but I can't seem to figure out the best way to deal with `y[n-1]`.

Comment: `np.cumsum` (and related ufunc accumulate) is the most useful tool for this.  Otherwise this kind of calculation is hard to express with operations that work on the whole array at once.

Comment: Let `t` be the array which sums `c1 x[n]` and `c2 x[n-1]`. If `c3` is one, then I believe `y` is just given by `np.cumsum(t)`, right?

Comment: I did it using `scipy.signal.lfilter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may use an IIR filter to do this. [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) is the correct choice in this case.

For my specific constants, the following code snippet would do -

```
  from scipy import signal
  inital = signal.lfiltic([1.001,-1], [1, -1], [y_0], [x_0])
  output, _ = signal.lfilter([1.001,-1], [1, -1], input, zi=inital)
```

Here, `signal.lfiltic` is used to to specify the initial conditions.

Comment: Does this have any time advantage?  If so, for what size of arrays?  I was trying apply this to another question, and for a small problem it was slower than the plain iteration.

Comment: I believe it would be having a C backend just like [http://www.numpy.org/](http://www.numpy.org/). I'm getting a lot faster results in my program as compared to a python `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Just by playing around with `cumsum`:

First a little function to produce your expression iteratively:

```
def foo1(x,C):
    x=x.copy()
    for i in range(1,x.shape[0]-1):
        x[i]=np.dot(x[i-1:i+2],C)
    return x[1:-1]
```

Make a small test array (I first worked with `np.arange(10)`)

```
In [227]: y=np.arange(1,11); np.random.shuffle(y)
# array([ 4,  9,  7,  8,  2,  6,  1,  5, 10,  3])

In [229]: foo1(y,[1,2,1])
Out[229]: array([ 29,  51,  69,  79,  92,  99, 119, 142])
In [230]: y[0] + np.cumsum(2*y[1:-1] + 1*y[2:])
Out[230]: array([ 29,  51,  69,  79,  92,  99, 119, 142], dtype=int32)
```

and with a different `C`:

```
In [231]: foo1(y,[1,3,2])
Out[231]: array([ 45,  82, 110, 128, 148, 161, 196, 232])
In [232]: y[0]+np.cumsum(3*y[1:-1]+2*y[2:])
Out[232]: array([ 45,  82, 110, 128, 148, 161, 196, 232], dtype=int32)
```

I first tried:

```
In [238]: x=np.arange(10)
In [239]: foo1(x,[1,2,1])
Out[239]: array([  4,  11,  21,  34,  50,  69,  91, 116])
In [240]: np.cumsum(x[:-2]+2*x[1:-1]+x[2:])
Out[240]: array([  4,  12,  24,  40,  60,  84, 112, 144], dtype=int32)
```

and then realized that the `x[:-2]` term wasn't needed:

```
In [241]: np.cumsum(2*x[1:-1]+x[2:])
Out[241]: array([  4,  11,  21,  34,  50,  69,  91, 116], dtype=int32)
```

If I was back in school I probably would have discovered this sort of pattern with algebra, rather than a numpy trial-n-error.  It may not be general enough, but hopefully it's a start.