# Translating for loop to matricial form

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, runge-kutta

I have created the following code to implement the [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) RK4 method:

```
 import numpy as np    
 u = np.zeros((steps+1, 3))
 u[0] = u0.copy()
 i=0
 h6=h/6
 for step in range(steps):
     k1 = f(u[i])
     k2 = f(u[i] + (k1/2)*h)
     k3 = f(u[i] + (k2/2)*h)
     k4 = f(u[i] +  h*k3)

     u[i+1] = u[i] + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)*h6
     i+=1
 return u
```

`f()` is the derivative function, which in this case does not depend on `t`. The method generates a 3d array of points which are the solution to the problem. Now I want to make this more effective by converting the `for` loop to matricial form, but I haven't been able to do it. Could someone help me?

Comment: @C.Dlp Because it is not needed. It is just a counter on how many steps

Comment: Does the `f()` function accept array input ?

Comment: @C.Dlp Yes, it does, as it works with `numpy.array` 's

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe should you try with `scipy.misc.derivative` and call it with an input function which returns an array .

Comment: In the `matricial form`, all values are calculated in parallel - yes there is iteration, but it's done in C code and buffered.   So if your problem is inherently iterative - the value at one iteration depend on values in the previous - you can't use most numpy methods.  `np.cumsum` is one the few that is iterative in nature, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366430/best-way-to-vectorize-operation-having-input-and-output-history-dependence

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use one of scipy's numerical integration methods? For example, [`scipy.integrate.ode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html#scipy.integrate.ode) with method `"dopri5"` is a Python wrapper around a Fortran implementation of RK4.